Reach an Azure VMs from a pod in Azure K8s cluster located in a different VNet
I've a pod running an application that needs to connect to another Vm to download some files.
The Vm and the Aks are on different VNets.
I've already peered those VNets and the link seems connected. However, the communication still does not happen.
Is there something else I should consider?
Additional Info:

The network plugin is Azure CNI
The cluster is not private for test purpose
The NSGs have the default rules


So when you do kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/sh
Inside the pod
and then do a curl -v http://<vm-ip>:<port> it is not connecting?
all your pods are up? Azure CNI assigns IP addresses from the subnet to each pod, and if your subnet runs out of IP addresses, new pods will not be able to start. This could be one reason for connectivity issues if new pods can't come up. Use Azure Network Watcher's IP flow verify tool to diagnose if network security group rules are blocking traffic from your pod to the VM.

Network Security Groups should permit traffic between subnets that require communication. Inspect the NSG rules to determine if they are impeding traffic. If there is no existing rule to allow traffic from one subnet to another, you should create an NSG rule and then verify the outcome.

When VMs and AKS cluster are in different VNets, Vnet peering is required, and you've already set up VNet peering.
Check the NSG rules applied to both the AKS subnet and the VM's subnet. Although you're using the default rules, ensure the NSG associated with the VM's subnet allows inbound ICMP traffic. By default, NSGs allow outbound ICMP but may block inbound ICMP. You'll need to add an inbound security rule to allow ICMP (protocol number 1) from the AKS subnet.
But I have a strong feeling your VM's firewall is the main root cause for connection failure. Check the firewall settings within the VM to ensure that it is turned off.

Here, I deployed a storefront app on my aks and as you can see pods are up

and the app is accessible.

So, if your AKS cluster is in one VNet (let's call it VNet A), and your VM is in another VNet (VNet B), they will not be able to communicate by default, because these are separate network segments within Azure.
To enable communication between them, you would set up VNet peering between VNet A and VNet B.

This would allow resources, like your AKS pods and VM, to communicate across the VNets which I did as shown above and disabled the internal firewall inside the VM and now both pod and vm is able to communicate with each other as you can see below-

So three things-

vnet peering
check nsg rules allowed or not
disable firewall inside vm

Reference-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies#network-policy-options-in-aks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-microsoft-defender-firewall-on-or-off-ec0844f7-aebd-0583-67fe-601ecf5d774f


